# Writing a strongly-typed object denormalizer in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, strong-typing

I have a dynamically typed data normalizer written in Javascript that takes a nested JSON response from a server, and returns a flattened object containing maps of the entities that were contained within the JSON response, keyed by the ID of the entity. To demonstrate, here's an example of how the mapper takes an input and produces an output:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": "CE3D6101-5D28-41F1-99C1-AB3829F52FDE",
      "name": "Lighting demonstration",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "CC23B72E-DA1D-45BF-8947-FB4549F31819",
          "creator": {
            "id": "12B18DB0-3EA4-4A27-87A7-23F1AEE42F66", 
            "userName": "Esteban Winsmore"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "CA4C65F1-83E9-4FF0-9D51-345CBBE27904",
          "creator": {
            "id": "1F020605-DD83-4E18-B13F-B24C25A2E9B4", 
            "userName": "Jesse Threebeards"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

This input is transformed to the following representation:

```js
{
  "jobs": Map<string, JobEntity>([
    ["CE3D6101-5D28-41F1-99C1-AB3829F52FDE", JobEntity()]
  ]),
  "tasks": Map<string, TaskEntity>([
    ["CC23B72E-DA1D-45BF-8947-FB4549F31819", TaskEntity()],
    ["CA4C65F1-83E9-4FF0-9D51-345CBBE27904", TaskEntity()]
  ]),
  "users": Map<string, UserEntity>([
    ["12B18DB0-3EA4-4A27-87A7-23F1AEE42F66", UserEntity()],
    ["1F020605-DD83-4E18-B13F-B24C25A2E9B4", UserEntity()]
  ])
}
```

Currently however, I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to reason about the exact typings needed to produce a typed input and output for this functionality. I suspect, but cannot prove, that this is not possible based on what the typescript compiler can achieve in terms of type inference and indexed access types. As a note, I am fine with adjusting the input or output shape if I can achieve complete type safety. Below is the current code and typings.

```js
type EntityConstructor = new (data) => EntityInterface;

interface Relations {
  jobs: Map<string, EntityInterface>;
  tasks: Map<string, EntityInterface>;
  users: Map<string, EntityInterface>;
}

class NormalizationService {

  private mappings: Record<keyof Relations, EntityConstructor> = {
    jobs: JobEntity,
    tasks: TaskEntity,
    users: UserEntity
  };

  /**
   * Given a nested JSON input, produce an output containing normalized data, each data type stored in its own
   * `Map`, keyed by the entity's ID.
   *
   * @param jsonData - An arbitrary JSON payload returned from the server.
   * @param entityName - The root entity type name that is being normalized.
   * @param normalizedData - An optional object conforming to the `Relations`'s shape. This is only explicitly
   * populated from recursive calls.
   *
   * @returns Partial<Relations> — An object containing normalized data converted from an arbitrary JSON payload.
   */
  protected normalize(jsonData: any, entityName: keyof Relations, normalizedData: Partial<Relations> = {}): Partial<Relations> {
    if (!(entityName in normalizedData)) {
      normalizedData[entityName] = new Map<string, any>();
    }

    [jsonData].flat().forEach(jsonObject => this.setObject(jsonObject, this.mappings[entityName], normalizedData));

    return normalizedData;
  }

  /**
   * Given a JSON fragment and an entity constructor, create a normalized entity, and set it in the appropriate
   * relation `Map`.
   *
   * @param jsonFragment - The JSON fragment to map to an entity.
   * @param objectEntityCtor - The constructor that shall accept the JSON fragment and create an object conforming
   * to `EntityInterface`.
   * @param normalizedData - The normalized data instance on which to add the entity to.
   */
  private setObject(jsonFragment: any, objectEntityCtor: EntityConstructor, normalizedData: Partial<Relations>): void {
    const entityForObject = new objectEntityCtor(jsonFragment);
    normalizedData[entityForObject.entityName()].set(entityForObject.id, entityForObject);

    this.recurseOverRelations(jsonFragment, entityForObject, normalizedData);
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param jsonFragment - The JSON fragment that should be evaluated for relations.
   * @param entity - The created entity from which to determine relations.
   * @param normalizedData - The normalized data instance on which entities should be added.
   */
  private recurseOverRelations(jsonFragment: any, entity: Entity, normalizedData: Partial<Relations>): void {
    entity.relations()
      .filter(relation => relation.instanceName in jsonFragment)
      .forEach(relation => {
        this.normalize(jsonFragment[relation.instanceName], relation.entityName, normalizedData);
      });
  }
}
```

Each `EntityInterface` conforming class (`JobEntity`, `TaskEntity`, etc) has a matching name in the `mappings` property in `NormalizationService`. That is, the property `tasks` provides the constructor for the `TaskEntity` type. I've tried to use index access types (i.e. T[K]) to somehow have the compiler infer the exact type based on the property without much success.

As it stands now, to utilise the output of the data normalizer, I have to explicitly cast the output properties to their respective types. This is what I'm trying to avoid. For example:

```js
const output = this.normalize(someJsonObject, 'jobs');
const jobsMap = output.jobs as Map<string, JobEntity>; // implicit type is Map<string, EntityInterface>
```

## Here are my questions

1. How can I instantiate my maps inside the `normalize` method with the correct `Entity` type for the Map value, instead of just `any`? I have tried making `normalize` a generic function with the following method signature, and then adjusting the body like so:

```js
protected normalize<K extends keyof Relations>(jsonData: any, entityName: K, normalizedData: Partial<Relations> = {}): Partial<Relations> {
  // ...  
  normalizedData[entityName] = new Map<string, Relations[K]>();
  // ... 
}
```

This doesn't seem to work well.

2. How can I make the `Relations` return interface have the correct `Entity` map type for each property, instead of just `EntityInterface`? As it stands, I am forced to cast each property to the correct type, like so:

```js
const jobsMap = output.jobs as Map<string, JobEntity>; // implicit type is Map<string, EntityInterface>
```

Is it possible to somehow have the typescript compiler determine the type of an object based on the runtime property name?

Comment: This may be unrelated, but there's an old question whose answer includes,"Types are stripped away at compile-time and do not exist at runtime, so you can't check the type at runtime," which seems relevant. (The question is called 'How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?' if you want to check it out ... I'm avoiding linking so others don't see a link and blindly assume there's already an answer out there somewhere.)

Comment: @Cat That's true; I'm hoping there's some way to use indexed array access of properties to infer the appropriate type. Even minor improvements to the type safety of this code are appreciated though.